# Perfect way to render a Ajax popup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am developing a content management system for a clothing shop. They can add/edit/delete through the CMS. I am using Zend framework and jquery too. My application works fine. However the server suddenly started to take much more time to respond. Then I  got a doubt regarding the way I developed the system. Specially for edit things.

I have two methods to display a ajax popup. Let's say for edit a product.

Method 1:

Once user click the edit button, It will request the relevant page from the server. I used separate view for each popup and I designed it using CSS. Data has been populated using a Zend form.

Method 2 :

Once the page is loading, I sent another request to a view which has the basic layout of the edit screen. So ultimately I have the source of the edit screen once the page is loaded. but with no data. If the user click edit button. It will send a request to the server and the server response a JSON. Then I process the json and populate the edit screen with javascript.

This is more text. But I wrote everything to understand you my issue. Please justify which method is the most suitable for this kind of work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a hidden `<div>` somewhere in your page with a `<div id="editPage" style="display:none;"></div>` Then, make the ajax call to a view with HTML to populate that div and the show it. That way you'll avoid popups alltogther. So, using Jquery

```
$('#editPage').load('/myEditAction/', function(){
  $('#editPage').show(); // you could even animate it in with a slider, etc.
});
```

for the Edit submit button, you could pass it back the same way via ajax:

```
//you'll have to use live here not bind, because it will come in via ajax...
$('#editSubmit').live('click', function(){
  $.post('/editSubmitAction',$('#edit-form').serialize(), function(data){
    //you can use the data from the post for thank you message, etc.
    $('#editPage').hide();
  });
});
```

Ajax is fun and easy with Jquery, imho.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that having a popup or AJAX request makes any significant difference on your server, but it's possible that you have some javascript which doesn't perform well.

- Are all the server requests slower now?
- Is the performance comparable on your development environment and the production environment?
- If you use the browsers developer tools to monitor the network request does it show the longest part of the page render is latency with the server?